# Doing greatest common divisor function with Haskell using until

Tags: haskell

I need help proggraming a function in Haskell to calculate the greatest common divisor. The problem is I need to use the until function which I'm not being able to implement. I tried using the following code (that didn't work):

```
mygcd a b = until (==0) (`mod` (a b)) b
```

Thank for your help!

Comment: What were you having trouble with?

Comment: Your syntax is wrong, so you might want to look into your understanding of things like function application.  For example `(\`mod\` (a b))` would apply the function `a` to the value `b` and use that as the second argument to `mod` (via section application which syntacticly looks like `\`someFunction\``).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try something like this (pseudocode)

```
mygcd a b = finalize (until endState nextState (a,b))
   where
   finalize (x,y)  = ...
   endState (x,y)  = some condition here
   nextState (x,y) = (x',y') computed in some way using mod
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer! It worked but I was looking for something simpler. But your answer helped me solving another problem so thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
mygcd a b = until (==0) (`mod` (a b)) b

> :t until
until :: (a -> Bool) -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
```

So we have our predicate `(==0)`, our function `` (`mod`(a b)) ``, and starting value `b`. My first issue with this, however: this won't terminate until the predicate holds true, so it can never produce anything but 0. What does that tell us? We also see that `a` must be of type `Integral a => a -> a` since it's applied to `b` to get something we can use in `` b `mod` x ``. And repeating that won't yield a different result, so the expression either produces 0 immediately or after one `mod`, or never finishes.

I think, to get something useful out of `until`, you need a more complicated predicate than an equality check. Perhaps a question like "what's the lowest multiple of 13 over 100", or you might make `a` a tuple and check one part of it. It looks a bit to me like:

```
until p f v = head (dropWhile (not . p) (iterate f v))
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you very much for both the explanation and the answer!